# Button with multi-line label bringing troubles with column layout

Tags: javascript, css, extjs4, extjs

I'm creating a dynamic panel with buttons. De buttons have an image 'big' image and a label. For longer labels I want multi-line labels. Using css you can force multi-line bij setting `white-space: normal`. But then the button on the next line snaps to the end of the line.

I've set up 2 jsfiddle's

One with the `.launchpad-button  .x-btn-inner`  white-space commented out.

[jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mAgfU/119/)

looks fine only I want the full text (so multi-line)

[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mAgfU/118/)

looks not so fine.. how should I fix this?

**Edit:**

Ow snap! It works using ScottS' solution but when my window resizes or there isn't enough space I get this issue: The new line (clear: left) is in the wrong place

[image: new line in the wrong place]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each is only three columns wide, then adding a `cls: 'new-row'` to every 4th item in your `xtype: 'container'` with css of...

```css
.new-row {
    clear: left;
}
```

...[fixes the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/mAgfU/121/). A pure css3 (so [only working in modern browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/mAgfU/122/)) would not need the additional class `new-row` added to the script, but just this css to select every 4th element:

```css
.x-container:nth-of-type(4n) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: hmm, not each will be 3 wide and sometimes there will be a container inside with more buttons (also column layout like this). With some logic I can put the 'clear: left's in the right place... I'll check it out tomorrow thanx in advance

Comment: I found a new issue. (updated my question) When I haven't got enough space. It should snap to the new line, that's one of the reasons I chose column layout. But now my clear line is in the wrong place!

Comment: @VDP--If you are programmatically placing the `clear` (I think you are), then you would need to recalculate those placements on a window resize to the new desired column width. If you are using the CSS3 `nth-of-type` solution, then you could set up an `@media` query to have the css make the change based on window size.

Comment: Yes indeed I added it programmatically. Can't use media queries or advanced css3 selectors (forgot to mention IE7-8 needed to be supported). Guess it means little more programming logic. ;) tyfta!